# Запретить вывод подсказок у input форм

Tags: html, css

Часто под формами, при вводе текста, появляется поле с данными, которые мы вводили прежде. Возможно ли запретить появление подсказок?

Comment: https://webref.ru/html/input/autocomplete

Comment: <input type="text" autocomlete="off">